# How do I complete the 'Loud and Clear' quest undetected?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Good news everyone! I've been inducted into the Thieves Guild.

Unfortunately, I'm already failing miserably on my first quest.
I've been assigned the task of destroying a bunch of beehives at the Goldenglow Estate as well as stealing the proprietor's life-savings from his house.

I've managed to infiltrate the house (using the handy sewer system) but I can't maneuver around the island without getting caught by one of the patrolling guards (even while sneaking). They attack me on sight, figuring that I'm up to no good.

Is there a way to successfully avoid these men so that I can get to the beehives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no real reason to complete this undetected (except for personal feel-goodsies, perhaps). The mercenaries guarding this place are nameless, "Mercenary" NPCs, so I wouldn't worry too much about killing them.

That said, your best bet is the same way you go about undetected in general - strip naked (armor is noisy!), hit up the dark corners, and make sure to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> (the default) to go extra slowly.

Comment: Wow...so I can kill the mercenaries? I thought I wasn't allowed to kill anyone! Have you tried killing them and know this for real or is it just speculation?

Comment: @spugsley I've completed the quest. I killed those SOBs.

Comment: You've made my day. I'm about to go kill me some mercenaries :)

Comment: Or just hit once Caps Lock to go extra slow...

Comment: The only restriction is killing Agronaith and burning all hives which will fail the quest.

Answer (score 3):

When I was on the island a dragon came, randomly, burning all the beehives.. um.. yeah.. also, if you have the summon dragon shout, use it.

The only person you're not allowed to kill is the owner of the house, the mercenaries are free to kill, so go ahead, you won't be at a loss of any special reward or anything.

Mercenaries are always okay to kill AFAIK

Comment: -1 You can kill the owner of the house if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I competed this mission without killing anyone at all.

As an Argonian, I can hide underwater forever, so I went through the sewers. This allowed me to avoid the NPCs outside. The last mercenary is right in the way, however, so I shot an arrow against the far wall. He went over and I went past him to break the safe and run home. It was very effective, plus it felt like the good old Thieves Guild way!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it without being detected by doing it in two part. First, I did the objective in the house by going trough the sewer, sneak-killing the mercenaries in my way.

Then, after I got the content of the safe, I got off the island and swan around it, near the beehives. Here, you can use the rock to jump on the island and burn the hives without having to go trough the whole island and avoiding the guards.

Answer (score 0):

Get ready with your fire spell and just charge through the bee hives and burn it. After that, just jump into the water and flee. I did it, done the mission without killing any..

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get through undetected is to wear a pair of muffle boots and sneak around using invisibility.   Super easy stealth.